# Error in defining a function that defines another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nameerror

(Note:-**You can just scroll into the bold parts for the main information**.)
Thank you for investing your time in answering my question. I have a python-3 **error in defining a function that defines another function** with the following code:

```py
def one():
    def two():
        print("two()")
one()
two()
```

And error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\homec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\test.py", line 60, in <module>
    two()
NameError: name 'two' is not defined
```

After defining `one()`, **I called `one()` so I defined `two()`**. Then **I called `two()` so I printed `"two()"`**. Then what is the problem here, **why is it saying `name 'two' is not defined`**.
Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: HINT: scope of the definitions

Comment: @tibebes Please give an answer instead of hint.

Comment: Usually there is never any need to nest functions. `two()` is only available within `one()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `two` just isn't available at the outer/global scope.

See this example on how to define it at the global scope:

```py
In [7]: def one():
    ...:     global two
    ...:     def two():
    ...:         print("two()")
    ...: one()
    ...: two()
two()
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought of a work around like this man. This is great if we want to define a function but don't wanna have any other alias for it.

Comment: If you don't want another alias you can just give the variable the same name of the inner function instead of x or func. @Navaneeth Reddy

Comment: @JLeno46 I do that if I am making a decorator with complex functionality. But honestly, this code is genious.

Comment: Why not just put `global two` before the `def`? Using `globals()` like that is an ugly and unnecessary hack.

Comment: @Tibebes.M You're welcome. However, I wouldn't call it a "workaround/hack". The way your updated answer uses `global` is exactly as designed.

Answer (score 1):

You defined the function `two` inside of function `one` and didn't even return it. Even if you return it, you have to store the return value in some variable then call that variable as a function. Try this code:

```
def one():
    def two():
        print("Two")
    return two

func = one()
func() #outputs 'Two'
```